# textscan Unexpected Empty Cell with valid Format string

Tags: matlab, format, textscan

I am reading a tab-delimited file.  Five representative lines of this file are:

> > Date Time    Property    Path 1  Path 2  Path 3  Path 4  Path 5  Path 6  Path 7  Path 8
> >     Lev 1    Lev 1   Lev 1   Lev 1   Lev 1   Lev 1   Lev 1   Lev 1
> >
> > 1/1  00:00:00    F1 (sm³/s)  -1.3405E-003    -1.1170E-002    -1.0123E-004    9.7769E-003 -8.4673E-004    1.1710E-003 2.6890E-004 2.2413E-003
> >
> > 1/1  01:00:00    F1 (sm³/s)  1.9988E-004 1.6655E-003 2.2252E-004 1.6883E-003 1.8612E-003 2.0221E-004 2.0795E-004 1.7333E-003
> >
> > 1/1  02:00:00    F1 (sm³/s)  -4.0722E-004    -3.3931E-003    -4.4324E-004    -2.1177E-003    -3.7075E-003    -2.5364E-004    -3.7330E-004    -3.1115E-003

When I use the following format string I get the expected results:

```
test = '1/1 00:00:00    F1 (sm³/s)  -1.3405E-003    -1.1170E-002    -1.0123E-004    9.7769E-003 -8.4673E-004    1.1710E-003 2.6890E-004 2.2413E-003';

textscan(test, '%*s %*s %*s %*s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f')
```

Gives me:

```
ans = 

[-0.0013]    [-0.0112]    [-1.0123e-04]    [0.0098]    [-8.4673e-04]    [0.0012]    [2.6890e-04]    [0.0022]
```

Which is what I want, but when I attempt:

```
    C = textscan(fid,...
             '%*s %*s %*s %*s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f',...
             'CollectOutput', false,...
             'Headerlines', 2);
```

I get a 1x8 cell of empty cells.

**What is the error in the format string translation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your format string specifically.

Try pulling in the lines individually with `fgetl` or similar and just check that there's nothing you weren't expecting in the file. For example - your code seems to work for me but I can replicate your error by putting an additional blank line at the start of the file, which causes `textscan` to try and read the second header line as a line of data (and fail inelegantly).  That particular error can be removed by increasing the value of `HeaderLines`.

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
fgetl(fid)  % repeat until you see your first line of data
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I try to use you code and it's work!

```
file=('d.txt');
fid=fopen(file);
C = textscan(fid,...
         '%*s %*s %*s %*s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f',...
         'CollectOutput', false,...
         'Headerlines', 2);
```

Output:

```
celldisp(C)
```

C{1} =

```
            -0.0013405
            0.00019988
           -0.00040722
```

C{2} =

```
              -0.01117
             0.0016655
            -0.0033931
```

C{3} =

```
           -0.00010123
            0.00022252
           -0.00044324
```

C{4} =

```
             0.0097769
             0.0016883
            -0.0021177
```

C{5} =

```
           -0.00084673
             0.0018612
            -0.0037075
```

C{6} =

```
              0.001171
            0.00020221
           -0.00025364
```

C{7} =

```
             0.0002689
            0.00020795
            -0.0003733
```

C{8} =

```
             0.0022413
             0.0017333
            -0.0031115
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a problem where my textscan would only grab empty cell arrays, google search led me here. I solved it by using fgetl(fid) a couple of times and then frewind(fid), (fid being your variable for fopen) something about reading the lines made it easier to bring in the values.